# How do I use mini login in header of magento?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

How do I use mini login in header of magento? I'd also like the login form to be disabled after login.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your `customer.xml` file in /app/design/frontend/PACKAGE_NAME/TEMPLATE_NAME/layout

This code adds the mini login form to the left column:

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="mini_login" template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml" /> 
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```